# Angular2 "No provider for Service!" error when provider is added @NgModule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-modules

I have an app module and single component application (made to demonstrate my problem), and getting following error:

```
 Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for UserService! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

code for AppModule:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UserService } from './components/common/userservice';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
providers: [UserService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
entryComponents: []

})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Code for my AppComponent:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { UserService} from './userservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'App',
  template: `<h3>App component</h3>                                                                                      
            user name: {{userName}}
            `,
  providers: []
  })

export class AppComponent  {

  userName: string;
  constructor(userService: UserService) {
      this.userName = userService.userName;   
  }    
}
```

My UserService Code:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    obs$: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()
    userName = 'Sherlock Holmes';
}
```

Now if i add UserService as provider to AppComponent, it will solve the issue. but i dont want to, because i want only one instance of my service in whole application. Even in subModules(feature modules).

according to my understanding, if i add service as provider on module level, then i can just inject it to any component under module.

here is am example i was watching.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WOswZ9qyTumCl7WgYd54?p=preview)

am using angular2 version: "2.0.0"

Comment: Please post your `UserService`; is it decorated with `@Injectable()`? (Unless it's exactly what's in the example Plunker of course...)

Comment: Also, your import path might be wrong: you use `/Common` in one and `/common` right below...

Comment: @msanford post updated, User service added. paths are fine,as imported classes are appearing in visual studio intellisense.

Comment: @msanford your were right actually. path is case sensitive. Visaul studio accepts it but it wont work in application. you can post answer so that i can mark it as answer.

Comment: Done! Also, that's annoying. The whole purpose of using IDEs is to find stuff like this for you. I've had good success with Webstorm, if that's an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The import path is wrong: you use `/Common` in one and `/common` right below.

Visual Studio and WebStorm will not show IntelliSense errors for case-sensitivity of paths.

Furthermore, if using Angular 5's AoT template compilation, you can get a "This component is not part of a module" error, even though it is, because the import path is incorrect. Without AoT this will work, so you'll get a surprise when converting to AoT.

Comment: So annoying. Took me hours looking at barrel and provider setup and it turned out to be a case sensitive issue with a service in a barrel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your service: `UserService` from `app.module.ts`, then add in `component`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'App',
  template: `<h3>App component</h3>                                                                                      
        user name: {{userName}}
        `,
  providers: [UserService]
})
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, for that you have to inject your **service**  `providers: [UserService]` in  `app.component.ts` (root component) which will be available in whole your application.

Comment: as i mentioned in post. I dont want to add it to component providers. If i added it in module, it should be injected in component automatically.

Answer (score 0):

An additional reason for getting this error - I duplicated a service to a different directory and was updating each file individually.  Even though the first file still existed I got this error until I updated app.module.ts.